# Why does \thanks shift the title page to the next page?

Tags: titles

I was trying to write a report work and when I was trying the `\thanks` command just below the author command it shifted the title page to the next page, making the first page blank.

---

Thank you!
Here is the code which I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={20mm,20mm},hmargin={20mm,10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}

\setlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}{0.5 cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}{ 0.5 cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}{ 0.5 cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}{ 0.5 cm}
\makeatletter

\newlength{\Page@FrameHeight}
\newlength{\Page@FrameWidth}

\AddToShipoutPicture{
  \thinlines
  \setlength{\Page@FrameHeight}{\paperheight-\PageFrameTopMargin-\PageFrameBottomMargin}
  \setlength{\Page@FrameWidth}{\paperwidth-\PageFrameLeftMargin-\PageFrameRightMargin}
  \put(\strip@pt\PageFrameLeftMargin,\strip@pt\PageFrameTopMargin){
    \framebox(\strip@pt\Page@FrameWidth, \strip@pt\Page@FrameHeight){}}}

\makeatother
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\title{EFFECTS OF TEMPERATURE AND RELATIVE HUMIDITY ON THE COMPOSITE MATERIALS}

\author{Ketan Karkare }
\date{18th April 2022}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\centering
\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

MATTER HERE (NOT SHOWING WORK RELATED

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always here, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy as is that shows your problem. That makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: you should always show your code but `\thanks` should be inside `\author{...}` not after it

Comment: Although it doesn’t help that some document classes require the `\thanks` after `\author` 